# How to set PUBLIC_HEADER to a list of files?

Tags: cmake

I am building a shared library written in C++. It is made of 2 classes hence 2 source files and 2 header files. In addition, a 3rd header file includes the 2 others for simplicity of use. So I want to install **3** public headers.

The problem is that the `PUBLIC_HEADER` property is set to the **1st file only**, instead of a list of 3 files (comma separated string). I checked it with `get_target_property()`. As a consequence, only this file is copied. The `FRAMEWORK` property doesn't seem to change anything.

Eventually, I managed to copy them all with `install(FILES)`, but it does not seem to be very clean. How can I improve this ?

CMake version: 3.16.

```
set(RST_PUBLIC_HEADERS
    "rst.hpp"
    "CPrbs.hpp"
    "CRstController.hpp"
    )
set_target_properties( ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    FRAMEWORK TRUE
    PUBLIC_HEADER ${RST_PUBLIC_HEADERS}
    )
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include/lib${PROJECT_NAME}
    )
```

Comment: Well, given the complexity of the linked answer, I think I'll better be off with the install(FILES) option...

Comment: The linked answer is similar, but different: this seems to be more specific, and I happen to have a simpler way to solve it. I just can't write an answer because it is closed :/

Comment: This should work `PUBLIC_HEADER "rst.hpp;CPrbs.hpp;CRstController.hpp"` if you don't use `RST_PUBLIC_HEADERS` variable.

Answer (score 5):

Does wrapping the variable in quotes address your problem?

```
set_target_properties( ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    FRAMEWORK TRUE
    PUBLIC_HEADER "${RST_PUBLIC_HEADERS}"
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I spent hours looking into this problem and using quotes solved it. It's a shame the CMake documentation provides so little information.